# Android Gradle multiple .so flavors

Tags: android, gradle, native

I have lib1.so, lib2.so and lib3.so. These are placed in different flavors but when building, the libraries are skipped and not included in the apk.
Is there a way to select each library based on flavor.

- lib1.so is for x86 and android 16+
- lib2.so is for arm and android 11...19
- lib3.so is for arm and android 21+

these are dummy libraries for the market to properly identify my app compatibility

```
src
-main
-arm
 -java
 -raw
 -libs
  -armeabi
   -lib2.so
-x86
-arm21
```

All I need is that the folder libs to be put in the apk

Comment: Why do you have flavored native libraries?

Comment: I have different lib.so for different android versions...11 to 19 one type of .so and 21+ another type of .so

Comment: In fact it is a bit more complicated. My app runs binaries not libraries and I had to put a dummy lib.so so it is detected by the market as compatible to a specific CPU

Comment: Could you show us your project folders structure?